# Move Points(pipe pointer position programatically)

Tags: revit-api, revit-2015

I want to move  pointer for creating Pipe from one place to another place Programmatically while drawing Pipe from revit.

please refer below image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMlX2.png)

while drawing pipe from revit i am able to change offset(Ex. from 15 to 16). but unable to change create pipe pointer location from red point to orange point(refer image) Programatically.

Is this possible?

OR

can we change or access Offset value Programatically while drawing Pipe from Revit.

Refer below image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FURFS.png)

Please suggest..

Regards

Namit Jain

Comment: Using code you can place the pipe where you want. The Revit API have some changes from one version to the next, so please clarify the version and the programming language you're using.

Comment: Using Revit 2016 with c#

Comment: To clarify: you want to make these changes while interactively drawing in Revit? or you want to make these changes while programmatically creating pipes in Revit?

Comment: Want to change Offset while Pipe is in Pointer...

Comment: And there's no pointers in C#...  There are references, which can be used similarly, but I think it's important you use the proper terminology if you want to get the best results / answers

Comment: Was my answer any help?

Answer (score 0):

Via the `Autodesk.Revit.DB.Plumbing` namespace:  There is a function:

```
public static Pipe Create(Document document, ElementId systemTypeId, ElementId pipeTypeId, ElementId levelId, XYZ startPoint, XYZ endPoint);
```

And you can use that in your code like:

```
XYZ fStartPoint = new XYZ(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);  //Modify these values to your desired coordinates
XYZ fEndPoint = new XYZ(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);    //Modify these values to your desired coordinates

ElementId pPipeTypeId = pPreviousPipe.PipeType.Id;
ElementId pPipeLevelId = pPreviousPipe.LevelId;
ElementId pSystemId = pPreviousPipe.MEPSystem.Id;

if (pPipeLevelId == ElementId.InvalidElementId)
{
    Level lLevel = null;
    using (Transaction pTrans = new Transaction(doc, "Get Level"))
    {
        pTrans.Start();
        lLevel = Level.Create(doc, pPreviousPipe.LevelOffset;
        pTrans.Commit();
    }

    pPipeLevelId = lLevel.Id;
}

Pipe.Create(doc, pSystemId, pPipeTypeId, pPipeLevelId, fStartPoint, fEndPoint);
```

There are overloads for the `Create(...)` function, so take a look at those too.  If you're connecting `Pipe`s and `FamilyInstance`s like fittings, you can use the

```
public static Pipe Create(Document document, ElementId pipeTypeId, ElementId levelId, Connector startConnector, Connector endConnector);
```

which will connect them directly via the `Connector`s.  As for offsetting the pipes, what I did above should suit you best.  Good luck!

### Added Note (edit)

And the `Offset` in your second image refers to the `Z` axis of your plane.  You want to do something more like

```
var fTemp = pPreviousPipe.Location as LocationCurve;
var fEnd = fTemp.Curve.GetEndPoint(1);    

//Index 0 is the beginning of the pipe (where user started drawing) 
//Index 1 is the end of the pipe (where user stopped drawing)

XYZ fStartPoint = new XYZ(fEnd.X, fEnd.Y - .5, fEnd.Z);
double dPipeLength = 10.0;
XYZ fEndPoint = new XYZ(fStartPoint.X + dPipeLength, fStartPoint.Y, fStartPoint.Z);
```